# scroll div initially to right then to left inside an overflow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `overflow-x` div which contains horizontal list of various items in such a way that at a time not all elements are visible. It is intended that the inner contents of `div` is initially scrolled to rightmost side and then after the page gets loaded then after sometime (using `setTimeout()`) the inner content get slowly scrolled to leftmost, preferably with `.animate()` of jQuery.
I have tried `scrollLeft()` but not able to make it out for this.

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;whitespace:nowrap;overflow-x:scroll;>
                <div class="row" id="inner_row">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zero</td>
                            <td>One</td>
                            <td>Two</td>
                            <td>Three</td>
                            <td>Zero</td>
                            <td>One</td>
                            <td>Two</td>
                            <td>Three</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

PS: I am using **jQuery** also, so its functions will also work!
Also the `' should still remain scrollable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CSS solution

```css
#inner_row {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 100px));
  animation: goleft 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes goleft {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100px;whitespace:nowrap;overflow-x:scroll;">
  <div class=" row " id="inner_row" style="position:relative; ">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Zero</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Zero</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a way to trigger it using javascript

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('inner_row').classList.add('animate');
});
```

```css
.animate {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 100px));
  animation: goleft 2s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes goleft {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100px;whitespace:nowrap;overflow-x:scroll;">
  <div class=" row " id="inner_row" style="position:relative; ">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Zero</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Zero</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Comment: this works! but isn't there anyway from javascript or jquery so that it can be done with user events too?

Comment: @Lincoln sure, you can trigger it by adding a class with these changes. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (or please provide some more info & code)

```js
$(document).ready( () => {
  $('.row').animate({
    left: 0
  },3000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  width: 2000px;
  position:absolute;
  left: -1500px
}

td {
  width: 800px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style=>
  <div class=" row " id="inner_row " style="position:relative; ">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Zero</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Zero</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not this! but to scroll the actual content inside an **overflow-x** div, from right to left